Weird Nextjs middleware rewrite behaviour
I need help on an issue im currently struggling with. I used Vercels platforms starter kit and took the middleware parts for the custom domain rewrites. The rewrites itself do work but when I access the home folder I can also access the pages that should only be accessible via the subdomain (localhost:3000/tickets should not work only test.localhost:3000/tickets should).
I would highly appreciate it if someone could help me.
Here is my middleware:
import { env } from '@/lib/env'
import { Database } from '@/types/supabase'
import { createServerClient } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let response = NextResponse.next()

  const url = request.nextUrl

  let hostname = request.headers
    .get('host')!
    .replace('.localhost:3000', `.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN}`)

  if (
    hostname.includes('---') &&
    hostname.endsWith(`.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_SUFFIX}`)
  ) {
    hostname = `${hostname.split('---')[0]}.${
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN
    }`
  }

  const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams.toString()
  const path = `${url.pathname}${
    searchParams.length > 0 ? `?${searchParams}` : ''
  }`

  if (
    hostname === 'localhost:3000' ||
    hostname === process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN
  ) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(
      new URL(`/home${path === '/' ? '' : path}`, request.url),
    )
  }

  const supabase = createServerClient<Database>(
    env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
    env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return request.cookies.getAll()
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            response.cookies.set(name, value, options),
          )
        },
      },
    },
  )

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser()

  if (hostname == `admin.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN}`) {
    response = NextResponse.rewrite(
      new URL(`/admin${path === '/' ? '' : path}`, request.url),
    )

    if (!user && path !== '/login') {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
    }

    return response
  }

  response = NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`/${hostname}${path}`, request.url))

  const domain = hostname.split('.')[0]

  const { data: workspace } = await supabase
    .from('public_workspaces')
    .select('domain')
    .eq('domain', domain)
    .single()

  if (!workspace && path !== '/access-denied') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/access-denied', request.url))
  }

  if (!user && path !== '/login' && path !== '/access-denied') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }

  return response
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api/|_next/|_static/|_vercel|[\\w-]+\\.\\w+).*)'],
}

I tried to test if the middleware shows the expected behavior only the part for the home folder rewrite is in the middleware but same result.

import { env } from '@/lib/env'
import { Database } from '@/types/supabase'
import { createServerClient } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let response = NextResponse.next()

  const url = request.nextUrl
  let hostname = request.headers
    .get('host')!
    .replace('.localhost:3000', `.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN}`)

  if (
    hostname.includes('---') &&
    hostname.endsWith(`.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_SUFFIX}`)
  ) {
    hostname = `${hostname.split('---')[0]}.${
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN
    }`
  }

  const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams.toString()
  const path = `${url.pathname}${
    searchParams.length > 0 ? `?${searchParams}` : ''
  }`

  // Handle root domain
  if (
    hostname === 'localhost:3000' ||
    hostname === process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN
  ) {
    // Only rewrite to /home if the path is exactly '/'
    if (path === '/') {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/home', request.url))
    }
    // For all other paths on the root domain, return the default response
    return response
  }

  const supabase = createServerClient<Database>(
    env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
    env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return request.cookies.getAll()
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            response.cookies.set(name, value, options),
          )
        },
      },
    },
  )

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser()

  // Handle admin subdomain
  if (hostname === `admin.${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_DOMAIN}`) {
    response = NextResponse.rewrite(
      new URL(`/admin${path === '/' ? '' : path}`, request.url),
    )

    if (!user && path !== '/login') {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
    }

    return response
  }

  // Handle other subdomains
  const domain = hostname.split('.')[0]
  const { data: workspace } = await supabase
    .from('public_workspaces')
    .select('domain')
    .eq('domain', domain)
    .single()

  if (!workspace && path !== '/access-denied') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/access-denied', request.url))
  }

  if (!user && path !== '/login' && path !== '/access-denied') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }

  // Rewrite for subdomains
  return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`/${hostname}${path}`, request.url))
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api/|_next/|_static/|_vercel|[\\w-]+\\.\\w+).*)'],
}

These changes should prevent access to subdomain-specific pages (like '/tickets') from the root domain. The root domain will only rewrite '/' to '/home', while leaving other paths as they are.
To test this:

localhost:3000 should redirect to localhost:3000/home
localhost:3000/tickets should not work (it will likely show a 404 error unless you have a specific route for it in your main app)
test.localhost:3000/tickets should work as expected


Hey, thanks for your answer. The issue still exists with the changes you provided.
